# How to solve json/json.h: No such file or directory?

Tags: c, json, makefile, compiler-errors

I've this problem:
when I try to compile my program, doing `make` command, I see the following error:

```
 fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
   21 | #include <json/json.h>
```

I installed the json library throught the command `sudo apt-get install -y libjson-c-dev` and it was installed correctly. After that, I simply compiled the program adding `-ljson-c` to the makefile (I also tried with `-lcjson` and other names, none of them works). Here is my `makefile`:

```
ifndef MYDIR
    MYDIR=../../
endif

TARGET=$(shell basename $(shell ls -1 *.c | head -n 1) .c)
TARGET2=$(shell basename $(shell ls -r -1 *.c | head -n 1) .c)


CFLAGS  += -I$(MYDIR)/include   
LDFLAGS += -L$(MYDIR)/lib 
LIBS    += -litsStatic -lpthread -lm -lrt -lconfig -lgps -ljson-c

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -f $(TARGET)/.o
.PHONY:clean

all: $(TARGET2)

$(TARGET2): $(TARGET2).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET2)
    rm -f $(TARGET2)/.o
.PHONY:clean
```

Where is the problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: "and it was installed correctly." Where is `json/json.h` located in your file system? From where do you run your makefile?

Comment: "(I also tried with -lcjson and other names, none of them works)" You confuse linker with compiler. A missing header is a compiler warning. Option `-l` tells your linker to include a certain library. That is only relevant after compilation was successful which is not the case here. You should rather check whether you need to add another option `-Ixy` to your `CFLAGS`

Comment: my library is installed in usr/include/json-c how can I add it to the makefile?

Comment: You add your folder to `CFLAGS  += -I$(MYDIR)/include`. In your case the missing file should be in `/usr/include/json-c/json/json.h` if you add `/usr/include/json-c`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification or requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. Is the exact location of the include file `/usr/include/json-c/json.h`? (see https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/amd64/libjson-c-dev/filelist) Then you could use `#include <json-c/json.h>`